# Build a string randomly, not repeating

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016, concatenation

I cannot seem to find a way to do this.
I have five cells in excel.  I want to concatenate them into a string randomly.
I want to use each cell character once in the string I am building, so
I end up with a five-character string, no repeats.
Say, I have A1 = Y, B1 = u, C1 = 6, D1 = %, E1 = z
I want to build a string that has each character in a random order
uY6%z  or zY%u6  either are equally acceptable (et cetera)

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can perform a [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) in VB for applications (VBA), for instance using the algorithm implementation displayed [here](http://eforexcel.com/wp/article-37-vba-generating-unique-non-repeating-random-numbers-efficiently/#more-12475).

Be sure to use a good random number generator, a cryptographically secure one if so required. `Randomize` is only seeded by the system time, so I would not run a lottery with it.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it describes what you want?

https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2484-excel-random-number-no-duplicates-no-repeat.html

Once you get the no-duplicates list of numbers, you can use that to INDEX() into your values with CONCATENATE().

Comment: This does not really address my situation.  I am generating random characters to go into a password, so not all numbers,  A special character, an upper case letter, a lower case letter, a number, and one that can be any of the above.  The link seems to talk about numbers, and numerical testing.